# Kivy How to switch between to buttons on top of each other

Tags: python, kivy

I have two buttons on top of each other I want that the first one is visible and clickable..

But for some reason I see the first one with the logic of the second one can anyone help me out?

```
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            id:1jab
            pos_hint: {"x":0.38,"y":0.843}
            size_hint: 0.02,0.03
            text: "+"
            opacity : 1
            enabled : True
            on_release:
                print("You press plus button")
                app.convert_button_id_in_label_id("1jab")
                app.build_popup()
                self.text = ""
        Button:
            id:1jab-
            pos_hint: {"x":0.38,"y":0.843}
            size_hint: 0.02,0.03
            text: "-"
            opacity : 0
            enabled : False
            on_release:
                print("You press minus button")
                self.click_minus_button("1jab-")
```

Comment: What about not having two buttons, but only one? You could either change the button to show the label you want or you could remove and add the buttons when needed.

Comment: Ok how can I switch between them ?

Comment: One thing to be aware of: The property for `Button`  enable/disable is actually `disabled`, not `enabled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having two buttons you can only have one button and switch when necessary:

```
class TwoButtonLayout(FloatLayout):
    plus = BooleanProperty()
    button_plus = ObjectProperty()
    button_minus = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        button_plus = ButtonPlus()
        button_minus = ButtonMinus()

    def on_plus(self, instance, plus):
        if plus:
            self.remove_widget(self.button_minus)
            self.add_widget(self.button_plus)
        else:
            self.remove_widget(self.button_plus)
            self.add_widget(self.button_minus)
```

ButtonPlus and ButtonMinus would be two classes of your button, so that you can style them via kv. You can of course also just use a Button and change their values in code.